# Geolocator locates me in SF when I'm in Spain

Tags: flutter

Geolocator locates me in SF when I'm in Spain, any clue why this is happening?

I've tried different ways but don't really know where the error is coming from.

Every time I run the app the location I get is:

flutter: 37.785834
flutter: -122.406417

Which is the Apple store in SF.

```
        import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Location {
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
              forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));

      latitude = position.latitude;
      longitude = position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an emulator then the geolocator will give you Googleplex lat and LNG and if you are using an apple simulator then you will get apple silicon valley latLng. if you want to get your actual address, then you can set the lat and Lng in your emulator and simulator, and you can also use your physical device for your actual LatLng.